# Does the alternate I2C has the same performance as the ALT0?

Tags: i2c

With the BCM2711, there are two native I2C BUS:

- I2C0 (GPIO0, GPIO1)
- I2C1 (GPIO2, GPIO3)

However you can have alternate I2C bus according from §5.3 on the [bcm2711-peripherals-pdf](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.org/bcm2711/bcm2711-peripherals.pdf). For instance, we can have:

- I2C4 (GPIO6, GPIO7)

My question is:

Are the two main I2C buses faster than the other alternate functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chapter 3 of the [available documentation](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.org/bcm2711/bcm2711-peripherals.pdf) states that all of the *hardware-based* I2C buses on the BCM2711 (RPi 4) operate under the control of the Broadcom Serial Controller, or BSC. The RPi hardware and firmware are **closed-source**, but relying on the documentation, a reasonable assumption is: **"No - none of the hardware-based I2C channels are faster than the others."**

Just to be clear, I use the phrase *"hardware-based"* to designate I2C buses sourced by the BSC, and to distinguish from the "software-based" I2C buses. I've not tried a "software-based" I2C bus, but I've read they are not able to operate at the same speeds as a "hardware-based" I2C.

Both hardware and software I2C buses may be configured as *overlays* in `/boot/config.txt`. For details see your RPi's local filesystem at `/boot/overlays/README`, or at [The Foundation's GitHub site](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/blob/master/boot/overlays/README).

Finally, there is a [similar question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/108896/what-is-rpis-i2c-maximum-speed), and answers that may be of interest to you.

Answer (score 2):

All the 8 hardware I2C buses on the Pi 4 are identical.

> The Broadcom Serial Control (BSC) controller is a master, fast-mode
> (400Kb/s) BSC controller. The Broadcom Serial Control bus is a
> proprietary bus compliant with the Philips® I2C bus/interface version
> 2.1 January 2000.