# Does I2C clock also change if system clock is altered? Pi4

Tags: pi-4, i2c

SPI clock speed is tied to system clock so for example of the system clock changes the SPI changes. To prevent this you need to prevent power scaling/fix the frequency.

Is this also the case for I2C on P4?

Comment: What is a P84? Where did you get this misinformation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is Rpi's I2C Maximum Speed?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/108896/what-is-rpis-i2c-maximum-speed)

Comment: Not as that I can tell since I didn't see them talking about if a system clock impacted I2C speed.